# Complete space through a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(M, d)$ is a complete metric space and $f : (M,d) \rightarrow (N,d')$ is a continuous function. Then is $f(M)$ always complete ?

My guess would be no, if someone has pathological examples I would be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Completeness is not a topological property, so the $f$ in question can even be a homeomorphism. Take $M=[0,\infty)$, $N=[0,1)$, both with usual distance and let $f:M\to N$ be given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$. This is a homeomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$. In this example, $([0,\infty),|\cdot|)$ is complete and $([0,1),|\cdot|)$ is not.

It is worth noting that a metrizable space is compact iff some (equivalently, every) compatible metric on the space is complete and totally bounded. So completeness by itself is not a topological property, but completeness and total boundedness of a metric together do become a topological property. In the example above, the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism exactly means that the metric on $N$ can be transported to $M$ to generate the same topology (that is, $\rho(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ generates the same topology on $[0,\infty)$ as $d(x,y)=|x-y|$). We note that $(M,d)$ is complete but not totally bounded, and $(M,\rho)$ is totally bounded but not complete. No metric could have both properties, because the space is not compact.